# Can't Add Foreign Key in Table PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

New to MySQL / PHPMyAdmin although I've done some SQL before. I've tried to create a foreign key constraint on a table and was successful in creating this constraint with one table (Account - Standard) but not for (Account - Premium). This link contains screenshots and further explanations of the errors I am receiving. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVFuh.jpg

Comment: Please add your table definitions as text to the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.  Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you add an index to the column first?

Answer (score 1):

Constraint name should be unique. For example:
fk_username_standard, fk_username_premium ...

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem!